# How to go to another page when using button in each cell using Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a table with all the data and I want it to have a button for each data cell so that it can view more in detail.

Below is the table i have currently.

[image: table]

So i want it to go to another page with url http://localhost:9999/animeShop/query?fname=1

The fname is based on the cell number.

```
        //to get sql data
        List<Object> dataItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
        while (rset.next()) {
            SQLData item = new SQLData(rset.getString("name"), rset.getString("prod_desc"),
                    rset.getDouble("price"));
            dataItems.add(item);
        }

        //for table
        out.println("<form method='get' action='http://localhost:9999/animeShop/query'>");
        out.println("<table class='table table-bordered'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataItems.size(); i++) {
            if (i >= 5 && i % 5 == 0) {
                out.println("</tr><tr>");
            }

            int idNum = i + 1;
            out.println("<td> <input type='hidden' name='fname' value='" + idNum + "'>"
                    + dataItems.get(i) + "<input type='submit' value='Search' /> </td>");
            
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("<form />");
```

When i click on the button, the url is like this

http://localhost:9999/animeShop/query?fname=1&fname=2&fname=3&fname=4&fname=5&fname=6

I understand it is repeated 5 times because it is in the loop but I cannot think of any idea on where to put it.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you have one form with one destination URL but five submit buttons. Each of the buttons will send all the input field's content as parameters back to the server.

Is it real that you have

```
<input type='hidden' name='fname' ...
```

five times? How would you expect this to behave at runtime?

I suggest you go for

- have five different forms, each with their own fname field and value
- have one common form with only one fname field, but then clicking the button would have to set the correct fname value via JavaScript before submitting the form

Comment: I tried having different forms but it is still the same result. I think the main problem is I cannot get their value.